# How to use get_results() in widget front end?

Tags: widgets, sql

I'm trying to get_results() in my widget's front end, this is my current code:

```
public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
    echo $args['before_widget'];
    if($children = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts" ))
         echo "working";
    echo $args['after_widget'];
    }
```

However I'm getting error "Fatal error: Call to a member function get_results() on a non-object".

I need to access the database to create a menu with the page children. What's am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you can't access to it. Please try add `global $wpdb;` to your function.

**UPDATE**

For reference, in [WordPress Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) you will find:

> WordPress provides a global variable, $wpdb, which is an instantiation
>   of the class already set up to talk to the WordPress database. Always
>   use the global $wpdb variable. (Remember to globalize $wpdb before
>   using it in any custom functions.)

Answer (score 1):

add `global $wpdb` since you are using it in function, which has local scope .